# Dirty Image Quality Assesment Measure

Tags: image, image-processing, feature-extraction, noise

I was looking for a way to measure (image quality score) how dirty is the document in image processing. Example images below:

a. Dirty Backgrounds w/o Text

[image]

Can someone give me an initial idea to start my analysis? I was thinking of converting it into a greyscale , then summing up the image intensity levels of the image, then dividing it into 255, then that would be the image quality score? Please help me with this. Thanks.

Comment: "Being dirty", is a not quantified feature. Before any coding you have to be more specific about the dirtiness or the noise definition in your image. In other world in respect to what image you want to do the comparison? a complete white sheet? or a brown image without the curves in it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to be a little more specific in terms of limitations. Do you have labeled data? Can you label it? Can you generate it? (you have a set of known dirty images with a dirty score assigned to each ~ few hundred images should do it)

Assuming you do, I would train a Deep Learning CNN on this data, to output a score between 0 and 1.

Take a look at https://course.fast.ai/videos/?lesson=1 which is a very good beginners course, ai library and starting point.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'm assuming you don't have a really high number of samples (which is typical for these types of tasks). For finding a similarity score, it's not very optimal to just train a CNN with a score of 0 and 1 and solve as a regression problem.

Instead, from previous experience, I have found that Siamese Network and triplet loss based idea works much better as it's a somewhat meta-learning approach and works with few examples (few-shot learning).

The idea is you'll have a CNN with the last layer being an embedding layer, you select one anchor (the most representative dirty image from all the dirty images you have, and the most representative clean image from all the clean images you have)now you pass a clean image (+), and a dirty image (-) through the network, compare them with the anchor image, if the anchor is clean, then you try to make the embedding vector of the anchor (clean) and the + to be similar, and try to make the embedding vector of the anchor (clean) and the + to be dissimilar, and vice versa.

You can just take the L2 norm of the embeddings and take the difference, for same type you set the output 0, and for the different cases, you set 1.

There are many implementations available in Keras, PyTorch, Tensorflow. Here's a simple example, https://medium.com/@prabhnoor0212/siamese-network-keras-31a3a8f37d04